# iOS 9 Location Manager doesn't return old location

Tags: ios9, locationmanager

Hardware:
iPhone 6s
16GB
iOS 9.1

I am trying to update a Location Manager App from iOS 6.1 to iOS 9.1.

LM is setup as follows:

```
locationManager = [ [ CLLocationManager alloc ] init ] ;

self.locationManager.delegate = self;

self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters ;

[ self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization ] ;

[ self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation ] ;

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{

    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    NSLog( @“locations.count = %d”, locations.count ) ;

}
```

The App runs on the device and updates the location (lat and long) but
locations.count is always equal to 1. Therefore, I cannot get the previous location to calculate the distance travelled or the speed.

Comment: can you add more information, I can't get what's your issue

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply.

IOS 9 does not use:

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    //Code based on your requirements
}
```

IOS 9 responds with this error message:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Delegate must respond to locationManager:didUpdateLocations:'
```

The new Delegate is:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
// some code.
}
```

The locations array contains a list of previous locations. (It has to do with conserving energy when Location manager is running in the background.) The last item in the array is the current location.  The next-to-last item is the previous location.

My problem is that the Delegate returns only that last array item.  The present location.  Not the previous location.

Thanks again,
SxB

Comment: is your location updating when you move? Whats accuracy you used?